# Why does '300 is 301 - 1' return 'True' in Python?

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, allocation

Why does `300 is 301 - 1` return `True` in Python?

I would have expected Python to do something like store the values 300 and 301 at two distinct memory locations x and y respectively, then apply -1 to the value stored in y. As 300 is not in the special range [-5, 256] of integers which have a unique memory location, I don't see how Python (or CPython) can still understand that it can actually just discard y and add a reference to x.

Maybe what I am describing above would rather correspond to `300 is (lambda x: x - 1)(301)`, which indeed returns `False`. But then, what happens during the instruction `300 is 301 - 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpreter is free to optimize immutable built-ins all it wants. There is no "special range", that is *an implementation detail*. What is going on here is an example of *constant folding*. When the expression is *compiled*, Python simply creates references to constants, and caches constants for a given block of code. This is easily introspectable using the disassembler:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("300 is 301 - 1")
<dis>:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (300)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (300)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see it simply loads the same object for the `is_op` comparison.

And indeed, if we compile this code, the code object carries the 300 in the 0th position of the constants:

```
>>> code = compile("300 is 301 - 1", "__main__", "exec")
__main__:1: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>>> code.co_consts
(300, None)
```

Answer (score 4):

Things like this are accidents of implementation, and must not be relied on. Here under CPython 3.11.3:

```py
>>> 300 is 301 - 1
True
>>> one = 1
>>> 300 is 301 - one
False
```

The second in fact works the way you expected. Why doesn't the first? Because it *just so happens* that this version of the CPython compiler evaluates `301 - 1` at compile time, and finds the same result already in the code object's constant table.

In more detail:

```py
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f():
...     return 300 is 301 - 1
>>> dis(f)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (300)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (300)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

See? It loads the same constant object (for the int 300) as the operands for `is`. While it doesn't go on to do this next thing, it *could*: evaluate the `is` at compile-time too, and reduce the entire function to just returning `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Disassemble the byte code of the operation and you'll see that in this case the constant is pre-computed:

```py
>>> def f():
...  return 300 is 301 - 1
...
<stdin>:2: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (300)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (300)
              6 IS_OP                    0
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```